# Gedit plugin for HTML tag match

Tags: gedit, plugins

Is there a Gedit plugin for highlighting HTML matching tag? If so then please suggest me.

For example in this sample:

```
<div> //div1
    <div> //div2
    </div> //end of div2
</div> //end of div1
```

if my cursor is at end of div1 then I want div1 tag to be highlighted. So that I know if I have closed my tags correctly or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend the plugin ["Zen Coding for Gedit"](https://github.com/mikecrittenden/zen-coding-gedit#readme) for fast HTML coding.